# xampp mail send in windows 11 64 bit not working

Tags: php, email, xampp, windows-11

Previously I was using windows 7 32 bit and XAMPP with php 7.3 and phpmailer (with ISSMPT to false on localhost).

Was using [FakeSMTP](https://github.com/Nilhcem/FakeSMTP) to receive emails testing via localhost and it was working ok.

Now I moved to windows 11 64 bit and installed xampp with php 7.4.33

Same php scripts (forget-password.php etc..) are showing email sent, but no email is receiving in fakesmtp.

I tried changing sendmail.ini setting, php.ini setting with the help of many questions and answers given on stackoverflow.com related to this problem since last 6-7 hours.....but nothing helped...